# how do I change directory in ruboto running on android

Tags: android, ruby, ruboto

I'm using ruboto (ruby) on an android tablet. I'd like my source to be in a subdirectory of the usual default source directory. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the IRB I can change directory using 'Dir.chdir "subdir"'. But ruboto's SCRIPTS page still uses the jruby directory.

Comment: or again in the irb I can use 'require "subdir/rbfile"'. Still not ideal tho...

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated your motivation for placing the Ruby source in a subdirectory, so I'll speculate that it is for tidiness in a polyglot environment.  Also, I'll assume you want all the Ruby source in the same directory, including source for Activity classes.

Adding your path to both the Ruby $LOAD_PATH and the Android component search path has been combined into one method in `org.ruboto.JRubyAdapter.addLoadPath`.  In `JRubyAdapter.setUpJRuby`, you can find a call to `addLoadPath` around line 289:  https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/blob/1.4.0/assets/src/org/ruboto/JRubyAdapter.java#L289

You can add your own call below the existing one:

```
addLoadPath("file:" + apkName + "!/<your_path_here>")
```

That will add the path to the Ruby load path and the Android component search path.

If you have a clear use case, I would submit it to the Ruboto tracker at https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues .  It sounds like something more Ruboto developers could use.